# R -How to pass value in mongolite Query

Tags: json, r, mongolite

I'm using mongolite package to connect and retrieve data from MongoDB.How to pass  value in mongolite find query

```
##connecting mongodb

library(mongolite)

mongo<-mongolite::mongo(collection = "Sample", db = "Test", url = 
                          "mongodb://User:123@Wyyuyu:13333/ty2_U",verbose = TRUE)

## getting all data from collection data from collection below query is working fine.

values <- mongo$find()

## But I want to filter specific value by passing value.

 for(i in c("process","check","queue"))
{    

   values <- mongo$find('{"field" : i}',)
}
```

if I tried above code i'm getting getting below issues . please help me to resolve

```
Error: Invalid JSON object: {"field" : i}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your `i` is a variable, you need to create the string using something like `paste0`:

```
values <- mongo$find(paste0('{"field" : ', i, '}') )
```

but rather than a loop you could also use

```
values <- mongo$find('{"field" : { "$in" : [ "process", "check", "queue" ] } }')
```

Comment: Note that the `paste()` function needs to include the double quotes around the variable:
`values <- mongo$find(paste0('{"field" : "', i, '"}') )`