# Send String Dynamically through function in R

Tags: r, mongolite

I want to send ID dynamically to the following line.

```
out <- m$find('{"CreatedBy":"5ab0abb017aac60f443d517b"}')
```

Here the string I want to send dynamically is `5ab0abb017aac60f443d517b`

So basically a function that would read take the ID as input param and put it inside of it.

Something like.

```
fetchdat <- function(x)
{

  out <- m$find('{"CreatedBy":"5ab0abb017aac60f443d517b"}')


}
```

I might want to call it like `fetchdat("id")`

Someone suggested [R -How to pass value in mongolite Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069411/r-how-to-pass-value-in-mongolite-query/47069890#47069890)

```
fetchdat <- function(x)
{

  out <- m$find(paste0('{"CreatedBy" :', x ,' }'))
  return(out)

}
```

I run into following error

> Error: Invalid JSON object: {"CreatedBy" :5ab0abb017aac60f443d517b }

Comment: like [this answer perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47069890/5977215) ?

Comment: check my edit @SymbolixAU

Comment: you need double-quotes to surround the `x` too:  `paste0('{"CreatedBy" :"', x ,'" }')`

Comment: This works! thanks! if you want to put that as an answer, feel free to.